# Eclipse: Set Deployment Assembly from Command Line (or automatically)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on a Eclipse Maven project. I am trying to overcome the below situation:

- There are tow `pom.xml`s being used, one as a parent, and the other,
  child.
- I build the project from parent `pom.xml` path using `mvn clean install` command and then generate the eclipse project using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command.
- After doing this, when I refresh eclipse project from eclipse IDE, all the `Deployment Assembly` entries disappear. So I have to manually add the dependencies by selecting everything inside `Add > Java Build Path Entries > Select All`.

Is there any way I can automate adding these entries to deployment assembly? Maybe a command line option or anything else will help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you tell eclipse not to build automatically and build it by yourself in mvn and then run in eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same thing :)